# How to stop structured streaming query in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark

I just started a structured streaming from within bin/spark-shell in bash.

```
//readstream is from json

result.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

Once I started it Ctrl+C doesn't seem to work anymore. And in spark-ui the Structured streaming tab doesnt contain any 'kill' command.

What I did just closing the bash...